# Music - Create Acapella from Original track and instrumental

Tags: music, music-production

Just had an idea that it should be possible to 'subtract' instrumental tracks from orginal tracks leaving us with just the acapella version of the song.

In it's most basic form this would be:

`original.wav - instrumental.wav = acapella.wav`

Has anyone seen or created something along these lines out there?

I thought I would check what is out there then potentially try finding the difference of between the two waveforms in python if not.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example: What OS must it run on? How much money you're willing to invest when it comes to paid solutions? Do you always have `instrumental.wav` to substract, or must the software "detect" that?